# Error Function in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, function

Script:

```
USE Perpustakaan
GO
CREATE FUNCTION com(@id varchar(30), @tipe_item varchar(30))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (SELECT left(id_tipe_item,3)+''+left(tipe_item,3)
      FROM tm_tipe_item
      WHERE id_tipe_item = @id and tipe_item = @tipe_item)
```

result:

> Msg 4514, Level 16, State 1, Procedure com, Line 4
>   CREATE FUNCTION failed because a column name is not specified for column 1.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
USE Perpustakaan
GO
CREATE FUNCTION com(@id varchar(30), @tipe_item varchar(30))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (SELECT left(id_tipe_item,3)+''+left(tipe_item,3) AS MyColumnName
      FROM tm_tipe_item
      WHERE id_tipe_item = @id and tipe_item = @tipe_item)
```

Note "MyColumnName" and change it as needed.